Does anyone recognize this group presentation: $\langle a,b,c\mid bab = aba = c^2,c^4 = 1 , ac^{-1}b = bc^{-1}a\rangle$.
During my research I have stumbled  across this group: $\langle a,b,c\mid bab = aba = c^2,c^4 = 1 , ac^{-1}b = bc^{-1}a\rangle$.
I would like to know if anyone here recognizes this presentation, and if so, which group is this? All I know is that $\mathrm{SL_2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a quotient of this group. Indeed, letting $a = b$ yields $\langle\text{  } b,c \text{  }|\text{ } b^3 = c^2,\text{  } c^4 = 1\text{  } \rangle$, which is a presentation for $\mathrm{SL_2}(\mathbb{Z})$.

What do you mean by "recognizes"? You can certainly do some decomposition. The normal subgroup generated by $a,b$ has index $2$, and is an amalgamated free product of $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle a^c,b^c\rangle$. Both of these are quotients of the braid group $B_3$,  itself an amalgamated free product.

Once more, a closing frenzy... Why should this question be closed ? It is not trivial and there is work on it.

For what it's worth,  the group is automatic (that's a computer calculation), so there is a normal form with a quadratic-time algorithm to reduce elements to normal form.
